# acessing source code variables when executable is running in java

Tags: java, netbeans

I am running a tool named "fio" from my java code using process builder.the tool has its source code in C.i need to get values of some variables from the source code of "fio",when i am running the tool in my java code.I tried to search for the solution but could not find any.
how can i do it?can "environment variables" for processbuilder help?
here is the code i am using

```
        String line=null;
        ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder("fio","inp.fio");
        File f=new File("/home/nikhil/Nikhil");
        pb.directory(f);

        Process p=pb.start();
        InputStream i=p.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader ir=new InputStreamReader(i);
        BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(ir);

        InputStream err=p.getErrorStream();
        InputStreamReader rerr=new InputStreamReader(err);
        BufferedReader bferr=new BufferedReader(rerr);
```

Comment: You're probably going to have to use `gdb` or something to connect to that running process. I doubt that the Java debugger will give you visibility into that process' variables. Also, the `fio` app should have been compiled with debug symbols available.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on use of gdb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can use "shared memory" to share the variable value with another new C program i wrote,now i can call a function from this new C program that will return me the value of the variable which is "shared" in my java code using JNI.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you have access to the code for fio and can rebuild it. One mechanism you could use would be to have fio output the local variable state you are interested in to one of the output streams (stdout or stderr) that you are handling, and parse the values out of it as messages whenever it changes and fio outputs an updated value. That keeps the communication fairly simple.

If you have a lot of complex data, you might want to consider creating a separate communication channel (shared memory, for example, or named pipes, or a socket based connection) for shared state. If you are just interested in some cheap debugging, I'd just go with the first approach by outputting something like

DBG{var1}=<value>

to stderr whenever a value of interest changes, and have your stderr stream handler in Java record the state for use wherever you need it.

Comment: Yes i do have access to the fio source code,do you mean that i output the value of the variables i am interested in to say stdout,and copy that value from inputstream in my java code?

Comment: Yes, that would probably be easiest for a quick and dirty debugging solution. The Java and C process spaces are fairly independent, and a bit of printf on the C side and parsing on the Java side is probably the cheapest/quickest way to get a closer look for debugging. If there are many variables, etc, you could look at trying to run both in debuggers at the same time and walk through the code, but that gets hairy pretty quickly.

Comment: Well, debuggers are great for some problems, but it may be using a slegdehammer to crack a nut, depending on the scope of what you're trying to investigate. It's a judgement call.